# Cufon: line-height problem

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cufon

I'm trying to use something like that...

```
.cufon-font-style-1 { font-size:40px; line-height:-20px; }
```

it's not working in IE, FF, Chrome...

i changed my Docytype and nothing changed...

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative value with the line-height property. Take a look at this [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C Recommendations, negative values for line-height are illegal:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

According to Cufon Wiki > Styling
Values lower than 1.2 (which is usually the default) behave as if `line-height: 1.2` was set.
https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/styling

If you want your line height smaller than 1.2em, you might have to go into the font .js file and change the value of the `ascent` manually:

```
//MyFont_400.js
...
"panose-1":"0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0",
"ascent":"800", // adjust this value to match your desired line-height
"descent":"-19"
...
```

Answer (score -1):

you just add *line-height for ie line height and adjust height. when both are in IE and FF same just give the container padding .